# What is the secret to understanding MSDN COM documentation?

Tags: com, msdn

I am looking for "typical" way one navigates MSDN to get a COM class to do what they want.

Example problem:  I am looking for an API way to unblock a local file (remove internet zone/mark of the web from a file programmatically).

I found one post on stackoverflow.com that talked about clsid_persistentzoneidentifier. so i searched in MSDN and got to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537029(VS.85).aspx.  What I am looking for,is what one does after they get to this url. From this location, I am not able to figure what the sequence of operations should be.  How do I connect this IZoneIdentifier to IPersistFile? etc.  There must be something basic that I am missing wrt COM related documentation.  MSDN has interfaces and objects, but nothing that helps me visualize a "sequence" diagram of sorts. Nothing that will get me to understand which COM objects are from same class. hence can/or should be QueryInterfaced, adn which should be CoCreated.

Answer (score 4):

The documentation for that indicates a few things.

The first is that you can call [`CoCreateInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686615%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), passing [`CLSID_PersistentZoneIdentifier`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537029%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get an implementation of these two interfaces:

- [`IPersistFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687223%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)
- [`IZoneIdentifier`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537032%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

It also says:

> Use `IPersistFile` to attach the object
>   to the target file and `IZoneIdentifier`
>   to examine or to manipulate the zone
>   ID.

That being said, you can look at the documentation for `IPersistFile` here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687223(VS.85).aspx

It shows that there is a [`Load` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687284%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), which is what you want to call with the filename to load the implementation with details about the file.

From there, you can call [`QueryInterface`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682521%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on the [`IUnknown` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680509%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) implementation to get the `IZoneIdentifier` interface and then call the [`Remove` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537034%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) on it to set the zone to the local machine.

Answer (score 1):

For that purpose, if it's not obvious from the documentation, I like to find sample programs in which relevent APIs are used: either using Google, or perhaps from whichever of the Microsoft SDKs is relevent.

Microsoft SDKs, [for example this one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows_SDK#Windows_SDK_samples), include sample programs.